# Form submit to a text field

Tags: html, forms

How to make a form that submit to a text field below

```
<form action="">
Text: <input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
Post text: <input type="text" name="firstname">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use JavaScript for that:

```html
<script>
  function submitted() {
    formValue = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
    document.getElementsByName("firstname")[1].setAttribute("value", formValue); // Copy the value
    return false;
  }
</script>

<form onsubmit="return submitted()"> <!-- Call submitted when the form is submitted -->
  Text: <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br> Post text: <input type="text" name="firstname">
</form>
```

However, there is no need for a form for that. The `onsubmit` attribute is mostly used for when you want to alert the user that the form was submitted; the actual submission is done on the server through PHP or something else, and not through JavaScript (since the user has access to the JavaScript code and could change the input checking process as he wishes). Here you could simply have something like this:

```html
<script>
  function submitted() {
    formValue = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    document.getElementById("postFirstname").setAttribute("value", formValue); // Copy the value
  }
</script>

Text: <input type="text" id="firstname">
<button onclick="submitted()">Submit</button>
<br><br> Post text: <input type="text" id="postFirstname">
```